# c++ reading excel file containing data and graph

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I am writing a program to read a excel file using c++. i need only the two columns of the file and the excel file just dont contain fields...it also contains graphs. there are 10 columns and the two columns i need are the first and 7th. converting into CSV didnt work. Any suggestions plz.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running on a Windows platform?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file as CSV and then read in the CSV file using fopen. You also need to start doing your homework on your own and not asking people on the internet for help.

Comment: Looks like he has already tried saving as/converting to CSV, though he doesn't say why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can be driven programatically through its COM interface. Here is some code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE11\MSO.DLL" rename( "RGB", "MSORGB" ), rename( "DocumentProperties", "MSODocProps" )
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB" rename ( "Application", "VBApplication" )

namespace Excel
{
    using namespace Office;
    using namespace VBIDE;
}

#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\Excel.EXE" \
    rename( "RGB", "RGB_" ), \
    rename( "CopyFile", "CopyFile_" ), \
    rename( "DialogBox", "DialogBox_" ), \
    rename( "ReplaceText", "ReplaceText_" )

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    try
    {
        Excel::_ApplicationPtr excel( "Excel.Application" );
        Excel::WorkbooksPtr wbs = excel->Workbooks;
        Excel::_WorkbookPtr wb = wbs->Open( _bstr_t( "c:\\temp\\test.xls" ) );
        Excel::_WorksheetPtr sheet = wb->Sheets->GetItem( 1 ); // First sheet
        Excel::RangePtr range = sheet->Cells->GetItem( 1, 1 ); // Row, column
        _variant_t value = range->Value;
    }   
    catch( _com_error& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "0x" << std::hex << e.Error() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error" << std::endl;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

This code gets the value in cell A1 in a spreadsheet loaded from disc. You should be able to go from here to reading your two columns of data.